# How to download 19 digits number in CSV file using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, csv, json2csv

Im using a nodejs code to download a csv file which also contains 19 digits number. But after downloading Im getting a number in the format like "1.23457E+18". So If I try to expand or format this cells to text or number Im getting last 4 digits as 0000. But My actual number is 1234574654345678987.

```
        "Unique": jsonResult[i].dcp,
```

Im assigning like this. If try to add some special characters like

```
   "UniqueSysReference": jsonResult[i].dcp + "A",
```

Then Im getting the original number with A. But I need only the actual number. Im using

"json2csvParser". Can anybody please tell me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot handle big numbers and their operations. largest exact integral value is 253-1, or 9007199254740991. In ES6, this is defined as `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

you can use bignumber.js library https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignumber.js .it handles all operations related to big numbers.

```
//require it
const BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');

 //then you can convert your number to bignumber
    Unique": BigNumber(jsonResult[i].dcp)

  //if you want to show that big number as string
  console.log(BigNumber(jsonResult[i].dcp).toFixed())
```

Comment: how are you assinging that number value 1234574654345678987 to  jsonResult[i].dcp ?

Comment: are you converting it to a string?